# MySQL Injection - Error 1222 on union select when column numbers are equal

Tags: mysql, sql, code-injection

I am learning SQL injection, I have established the number of columns through `order by` lets say 100, but when I run `union select` on the same number above I get error 1222 returned:

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Why is this error returning?

Comment: Could you please post your code ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's caused by two queries running on the same page, both taking in user input, but both utilizing a different number of columns, therefore one of those two queries may accept that "order by 100" though the other query will not, and spit out the error to you.